# Python dictionary not updating values

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, dictionary, python-idle

I have a snippet of code that is supposed to update player's scores:

```
...

    self.players[speaker.lower()] += speakerScore
    for player in advisers:
        print(player, self.players[player.lower()])
        self.players[player.lower()] += adviserScore
        print(player, self.players[player.lower()])
    for person in liars:
        self.players[player.lower()] += liarScore
    print(list(self.players.items()))
...
    for player in self.players.items():
        print(player[0] + ": "+str(player[1]))
```

`self.players` is a dictionary that contains `player:score`, in lowercase. It is guaranteed to have all the players by previous code, and `advisers` and `liars` have the correct players. Here's what I'm getting as output:

```
a 0
a 7.694582912747661
[('a', 0.0), ('s', 15.389165825495322), ('l', 0)]
a: 0.0
s: 15.389165825495322
l: 0
```

For reference, `s` is the speaker, `a` is the only adviser, and `l` is the only liar. All of their scores start at 0, and 7.694582912747661 is the score `a` should be receiving. (`b` is also correct, and `l` should be receiving -7.694582912747661. Yes, the scoring is weird. I'm sorry.) I am editing this in IdleX, and testing it in IdleX's REPL. (IdleX is an improved version of IDLE, which is a Python editor and REPL written in Python itself.)

Why aren't the correct scores being put in?

Comment: `for person in liars: self.players[player.lower()] += liarScore` - sure that shouldn't be `person.lower()` ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, yes. Duh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't print anything in the `liars` loop, where you have an error; you used `player.lower()` while your loop variable is called `person`:

```
for person in liars:
    # ^^^^
    self.players[player.lower()] += liarScore
    #            ^^^^^^
```

Your output is consistent with `liarScore` being set to `-advisesScore`, and `'a'` being the last `player` value.

I'd change both the `player` and `person` variables to reflect the loop sources:

```
for adviser in advisers:
    self.players[adviser.lower()] += adviserScore
for liar in liars:
    self.players[liar.lower()] += liarScore
```

That way you are perhaps less likely to confuse the two.

Comment: ...Those are *debug* print statements. I didn't print anything in the `liars` loop because it should have been identical to the `advisers` loop. However, you still hit the reason for the bug. Sometimes, the problem is staring us in the face. I facepalmed when I read your answer. Strangely, despite `player` being in all positions in the `advisers` loop, changing it to `adviser` fixed it. Apparently, a previous use was confusing it. Programming is weird. Thanks for the help, and especially for the speedy reply! I actually planned on using this tomorrow, so I'm grateful that you answered quickly!